# Displaying the color equivalent of the hex code retrieved in a table cell

Tags: php, mysql

I need to retrieve the color hex code stored in a database and display it as seen on screen within a table cell. i'm trying to find a way to convert the hex code the db query returns for that specific table cell into the actual color that the hex denotes.  Here's my code...

```
<?php
                // Include config file
                require_once "config.php";
                
                $pdo = new PDO($dsn, $username, $password, $options);
                // Attempt select query execution
                $sql = "SELECT * FROM sales";
                if($result = $pdo->query($sql)){
                    if($result->rowCount() > 0){
                        echo "<table class='table table-bordered table-striped'>";
                            echo "<thead>";
                                echo "<tr>";
                                    echo "<th>S/N</th>";
                                    echo "<th>Transaction Date</th>";
                                    echo "<th>Customer Name</th>";
                                    echo "<th>Address</th>";
                                    echo "<th>Phone Number</th>";
                                    echo "<th>Vehicle Model</th>";
                                    echo "<th>Vehicle Chassis Number</th>";
                                    echo "<th>Vehicle Registration Number</th>";
                                    echo "<th>Vehicle Color</th>";
                                    echo "<th>Amount Paid</th>";
                                    echo "<th>Advance</th>";
                                    echo "<th>Balance</th>";
                                    echo "<th>Balance Due Date</th>";
                                    echo "<th>Paid To</th>";
                                echo "</tr>";
                            echo "</thead>";
                            echo "<tbody>";
                            while($row = $result->fetch()){
                                echo "<tr>";
                                    echo "<td>" . $row['id'] . "</td>";
                                    echo "<td>" . $row['transactiondate'] . "</td>";
                                    echo "<td>" . $row['customername'] . "</td>";
                                    echo "<td>" . $row['address'] . "</td>";
                                    echo "<td>" . $row['phonenumber'] . "</td>";
                                    echo "<td>" . $row['vehiclemodel'] . "</td>";
                                    echo "<td>" . $row['vehiclechassisnumber'] . "</td>";
                                    echo "<td>" . $row['vehicleregistrationnumber'] . "</td>";
                                    echo "<td>" . $row['vehiclecolor'] . "</td>";
                                    echo "<td>" . $row['amountpaid'] . "</td>";
                                    echo "<td>" . $row['advance'] . "</td>";
                                    echo "<td>" . $row['balance'] . "</td>";
                                    echo "<td>" . $row['balancedate'] . "</td>";
                                    echo "<td>" . $row['paidto'] . "</td>";
                                    echo "<td>";
                                echo "</tr>";
                            }
                            echo "</tbody>";                            
                        echo "</table>";
                        // Free result set
                        unset($result);
                    } else{
                        echo "<p class='lead'><em>No records were found.</em></p>";
                    }
                } else{
                    echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute $sql. " . $mysqli->error;
                }
                
                // Close connection
                unset($pdo);
                ?>
```

Comment: Firstly, you are not showing us the code where you are trying to use the colour. But why are you trying to covert it from Hex at all? You can use hex in HMTL.

Comment: `$mysqli->error` looks like mysqli code but you are using PDO..

Comment: See this example: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_td_bgcolor_css

Answer (score 0):

It is a bit unclear about where you wish to use the colour but I'm assuming it is here. And also my assumption is the retrieved value for vehiclecolor column is a HEX value

```
echo "<td>" . $row['vehiclecolor'] . "</td>";
```

You can use tag property 'background-color' for this.

```php
$temp = $row['vehiclecolor'];
echo "<td style='background-color:" . $temp ."'></td>";
```

Pretty self-explanatory I guess. String concatenation.